# Plugin description translation

Tags: plugin, installation, joomla3.8, system-plugin

I have problem with plugin description translation. After first install the description is not translated. After second install (without uninstalling) the description is translated. Where is problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved. The problem was in missing plg_system_name.sys.ini file.